# SwiftUI - Incorrect padding when using GroupedListStyle() for iOS 15

Tags: swiftui, ios15, xcode13

I have the following structure, more or less:

```
ZStack {
    NavigationView {
        List {
            Section(header: Text("1")
                                .padding(.top, 20)
                    footer: Text("2")
                                .padding(.bottom, 20)
                    },
                    ...
        }
        .listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
    }
}
```

For iOS 14 and earlier it was working properly, but in Xcode 13 beta 4/5, when running iOS 15, the padding is much bigger, as if there was a default padding added. I need to replace my values (20 in this example) with 0 in order to match the design.

Has anyone experienced such issue? Any solutions?

Comment: They changed the default design of List, just make your custom paddings conditional on system version availability.

Answer (score 1):

The only solution that seems to work for me is this:

```
List { ... }    
    .onAppear(perform: {
        UITableView.appearance().contentInset.top = -35
    })
```

-35 will remove almost all of the spacing, -30 is more like the spacing that was in iOS 14.

Answer (score 0):

The same thing happened to me. You just have to delete your DerivedData folder. You don't need to take make any changes to your code. Took me a while to figure that out.

Comment: This is definitely not the case for me. I've done all of that before and it didn't help.